# facebook like button on every element of my blog

Tags: facebook-like, blogs

i have been wondering how can i get url(of particluar article):title(of particluar article) on my facebook page if i like any article of my blog. 
 exp: prosoundnetwork:AV Meets the iPad by Christopher Maione

here prosoundnetwork: is name of my website and
    AV Meets the iPad by Christopher Maione :  is my article title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generator on step 2 of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ will produce the appropriate meta tags to include on the blogposts to get your desired description, etc to appear